# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY Using NDK

Tags: android

I am using a a project of Combination of NDK and android that is related to augmented Reality 
I want to and this project in another project.
I have read posts on different Question regarding this issue but they all are explicitly related to google map api.

I've made the other project as a library and now using it in my new project.
I've added permission in Manifest file.
Here are is the specific part of it.

`<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.VirtualButtons" />`

```
        <activity android:name="com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.VirtualButtons.VirtualButtons"
         android:label="@string/title_activity_putit_out_demos" />
```

so if any body can guide me where i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have figured it out with one simple way 
follow the steps to get rid off this thing
right click on the Project you want to make library
go to 
Properties->Android-> check is Library option (in right lower area)
click apply and then Ok
and go to main project in which you want to add it as library 
right click on it  go to properties-> android click on add button (right lower area) add the project 
click apply  and then ok
and in Manifest file 
and the main class of the library project to triger its functionality

```
`<activity>your activity goes here </activity>`
```

**No need to Add `<uses-library>` permission in manifest file**

Answer (score 1):

The only thing suspicious I see is the uses-library tag, do you have the lib in your device/emulator? If yes then you should have the following files in it,

```
/system/etc/permissions/com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.VirtualButtons.xml
/system/framework/com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.VirtualButtons.jar
```

Without the lib the apk installation will fail with INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error.